# Как проверить на уникальность данные перед добавлением в базу?

Tags: mysql

Хочу занести данные из чата в `MySql`. Перед вставкой данных проверю наличие записей по двум колонкам и потом вставлять в БД.

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM chat WHERE chat.nickname = 'МойНик' and chat.datecreated= '2021-01-17T07:00:32+00:00' = 0)
   INSERT ...
END
```

Всё работает, но хочется более элегантное решение. Допустим при вставке игнорировать дубли по `нескольким колонкам`. Что то типа `IGNORE`. Чтобы я каждый раз не проверял есть ли данные в БД. Данных много, поэтому это тормозит работу

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну да, именно `insert ignore` сделав уникальный индекс по полям nickname, datecreated

Comment: @Mike но она не даёт добавлять если nickname один, а datecreated  другая

Comment: почему ? один уникальный индекс на две колонки обеспечивает уникальность именно двух колонок в совокупности `cerate unique index teb_ind1 on tab(nickname, datecreated)`

Answer (score 0):

Надо было создать уникальный индекс по двум полям

```
create unique index tab_ind1 on tab(nickname, datecreated)
```